# Wildcard Syntax for Azure Search Simple Query Syntax

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using the Azure Search C# SDK version 5.0.1.  I am trying to perform a simple query that will search a field for a value that starts with something.  It would be equivalent to the SQL query of Select * From mytable Where myproperty = 'val%'.  According to the Simple Query Syntax documentation (located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/simple-query-syntax-in-azure-search)) this should be possible using a wildcard.  I cannot figure out how to get it working.  I have tried to populate the Filter property of the SearchParameters in the following ways:

1. "fieldname eq 'val*'"  Doesn't work
2. "fieldname eq 'val\.*'" Doesn't work
3. "search.in(filename, 'val*')" Doesn't work

Does anyone know of a way to perform wildcard searches using Azure Search .NET SDK with simple query syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards work in searches, not filters. You need to use it in the searchText parameter, not the Filter parameter.

Comment: I finally figured that out!  Thank you for pointing that out.  So when I use the SDK and perform a search like Documents.SearchAsync(@"fieldname:val* AND timeStamp:2018-05-03T13\:23\:59Z") it does not return the correct results.  There are exactly 2 documents in my index with that timestamp.  There are 121 documents in my index where the fieldname starts with val.  When I run the above query using the SDK, it always returns 121 documents. Is there some special way to query timestamp that I am missing?  Thank you, Bruce.

Comment: The timestamp might be encoded incorrectly. Are you doubling the backslashes in your C# code?

Comment: Also, is timeStamp a searchable string field?

Comment: The timeStamp field is a searchable string field.  I am double backslashing.  The raw query looks like Documents.SearchAsync("fieldname:/val.*/ AND timeStamp:2018-05-03T13:\\23:\\59Z").  It returns 121 documents every time.  It should only return 2.

Comment: The double backslashes should be before the colons, right? Something more complicated might be going on here. I recommend creating a new question and someone on the team with more specialized knowledge of Lucene query syntax than me will help you.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.  I'll post a new question.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you’re satisfied with this answer to the original question, feel free to mark it as accepted.